# Is there a maximum number of elbows allowed in a natural gas run?

Tags: hvac, gas, natural-gas

I know that in a forced air system, there is a maximum of  four 90s that can be installed due to pressure loss. Does this also apply to a natural gas run?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

Bend quantity is part of a total calculation also involving pipe size, segment length, pressure, device consumption, etc. There is no specific quantity limit.

[How do I calculate the capacity for my natural gas pipe in this situation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/268260/35141)

[Calculating gas capacity with mixed sizes of black iron pipes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/273816/35141)

[What size black iron pipe should I use for a 45,000 BTU attached garage heater?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/213399/35141) (see the relevant answer)